# How do I use the trigonometric functions in Python using the maths library whilst it being in degrees?

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

I am using the math library in Python to create a calculator. I have set up the trigonometric functions and they work however it is in radians. I cannot seem to figure out how to make a way so that the input can be in degrees.

After doing research into the math library I know that there is the function called degrees which converts a number from radians to degrees. In which I tried the following code.

```py
print(math.degrees(math.tan(45)))
print(math.tan(math.degrees(45)))
```

The solution of tan(45) using degrees to be 1, however the first line produced 92.806282178162 and the second produced -1.3620448762608375.

If there is an alternative library or way of writing the function myself then please let me know as my code doesn't depend entirely on the math library so I can make changes without having to rewrite my whole project.

Thank you in advance.